# How to store the RFID details(EPC,Reader_id,powerlevel) through MQTT in database..?

Tags: java, iot, rfid, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

I am using IMPINJ reader and tags to carryout this experiment.I need to store the identified TAG details in to postgres through MQTT.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would help people to answer if you could provide some more information and code snippets of what you have tried and specific hurdles you have come across